# E-mail for Workflow doesn't work

Tags: workflow, 2013, email

My workflow:

- Email XPerson Start
- Approval Process

When workflow works the approval process starts but don't send any email. The exchange settings are done. But are SMTP settings really needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are truly necessary! Please follow the Technet guide for [configuring Email for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx)

Comment: Ok. If I make it work I'll write back.

Comment: My workflow is 2010 in SP 2013. Can it be the reason?

Comment: No mather what you will still need smpt for the server to be able to send mails.

Comment: Thanks, I did the SMTP settings. I forgot the set outgoing email. Now it works.

Comment: I make the same settings to another server too but it doesn't work. I compared and checked every services in CA and IIS, every settings for SMTP. I couldn't find anything. Maybe I miss something. Which services should be enabled or need special settings?

Comment: How can you unmark this as an answer? This is the correct answer. Can't blaim me for your faulty server configurations

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to [Configure outgoing email for a specific web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx#section5)

Comment: Witch is the last step in my link! So please mark it as an answer.